# Как проверить является ли результат mysql_fetch_array пустым

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать так, чтобы $row не выводились, если нет записи в бд

```
<?php
    require 'scripts/connect.php';
    $sqlAdd = (!empty($_GET["sort"]) && $_GET["sort"]=='name') ? " Order by name" : "";
    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users".$sqlAdd;
    $result = mysql_query($sql_select);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    do
    {
        printf("<tr>
        <td>" .$row['name'] . "</td>
        <td>" .$row['last_name'] ."</td>
        <td><img src=/db1/scripts/upload/" .$row['img'] . " style=\"width: 70px;height: 50px;\"></td>
        <td>" .$row['email'] . "</td>
        <td>" .$row['facebook'] . "</td>
        <td>" .$row['time'] . "</td>
        <td>" .$row['spec'] . "</td>
        </tr>");
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
?>
```

Comment: `do {} while ()` -> `while () {}` не?

Answer (score 1):

Заменить цикл с постусловием `do..while()` на цикл с предусловием `while() {}`

```
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  printf(
   ........
  );
}
```

Comment: Все также, отображаются все столбцы https://jsfiddle.net/etr0ddcg/. Вернее как добавить к $row[img] условие. Если пусто в поле не выводить

Comment: @ВиталийНосиков Какие столбцы? Исходный вопрос был "Как сделать так, чтобы $row не выводились, если нет записи в бд" я показал как. О каких столбцах Вы говорите?

Comment: http://prnt.sc/d4sexd. В первой строчке нет данных в 3 стоблце, но он выводиться. Во второй строчке есть данные в 3 столбце он выводиться как надо

Comment: @ВиталийНосиков используйте оператор `if` или тернарный оператор вместе с функциями `isset()` или `empty()`

Comment: Да я вкурсе if. Но я незнаю как прикрепить к своему масиву

Comment: помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Если задача игнорировать строки с пустым img, то поставь первой строкой внутри цикла: if (!$row[img]) continue;